# Using Html and Css to create DropDown Menu but not able to navigate to all the submenu if using div to partition page

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am using Html and Css to create DropDown Menu in Vertical Direction as shown here.

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/techspartan/8u8NH/][1]
```

I am using div to divide my page in two parts such that menu is displayed on left side followed by some content in the remaining space. For example if width of webpage is 1024px than I am allocating 200px to menu and remaining 824px to div that has content. But after using div I am not able to navigate to submenu "3.4.1" and "3.4.2" as shown in the [url](http://jsfiddle.net/techspartan/8u8NH/) posted above as I can understand this is happening because the submenu is crossing the space allocated to it.

So how can I solve this problem and I don't want to allocate more width to my menu and that menu should be followed by content.

Any help would be most welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix is to ensure that the Z-Index is for your nav is higher than the z-index for your content.

The reason it's closing in your fiddle because once you touch the text, you're no longer hovering over your nav but instead hovering over your text.

```
#nav li {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 125px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Increasing z-index on the #nav li fixes this issue.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/8u8NH/1/)

Comment: still I am not able to navigate to 3.3.4 and 3.5.2 submenu. you can also check this in the fiddle code posted by you.

Comment: I'm able to in the fiddle that I posted. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE-10. I checked its working fine in Firefox but not working in IE-10.

Comment: Try adding: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to the head of your HTML or declare it as <!DOCTYPE html>